# GMSAutocompleteViewController crash on ios 15 only on release mode

Tags: swift, google-places-api

I am just presenting GMSAutocompleteViewController but it is crashing even though i have made separate application. Crash only happen on release mode but not on debug mode. But ealier ios 15 everything was working. I have added the api key in appdelegate and it is working on debug mode and below is the code:

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self
autocompleteController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Application Specific Information:
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
CoreSimulator 802.6.1 - Device: iPhone 13 Pro Max (13ED85A0-1287-44A4-B21F-CD56D7109BCC) - Runtime: iOS 15.5 (19F70) - DeviceType: iPhone 13 Pro Max
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <NSConcreteMapTable: 0x7f780792d7d0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot**

Comment: You should add some code, with explanations on how you set it up and how/when it crashes.

Comment: On debug mode it is not crashing so i cannot tell on which line it is crashing.